# Python Boto3 not receiving messages but SQS shows in flight

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sqs

I've a docker which fetches messages from a standard SQS. But most of the times, the code shows it received zero messages and exits. While the SQS console shows the messages under "Messages in flight", so the messages were received by some consumer.

This is my docker entry point

```
ENV PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/app"

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]
CMD ["multi.py"]
```

This is multi.py code

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import subprocess

def s():
    subprocess.call(['python3', 'script.py'])

n_process = min(mp.cpu_count(), 8)
process = []

for i in range(n_process):
    p = mp.Process(target=s)
    process.append(p)
    p.start()

for p in process:
    p.join()
```

This is script.py part of the code which calls receive_messages

```
sqs = boto3.resource('sqs', region_name=REGION, aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName=QUEUE_NAME)

def main():
    while True:
        m = queue.receive_messages()
        for message in m:
            process_message(message)
            message.delete()
```

Also, the docker works like 60% of the time. But I'm trying to figure out why it fails.

PS: Solved
This is from the boto3 docs

> Short poll is the default behavior where a weighted random set of machines is sampled on a ReceiveMessage call. Thus, only the messages on the sampled machines are returned. If the number of messages in the queue is extremely small, you might not receive any messages in a particular ReceiveMessage response. If this happens, repeat the request.

Comment: Looks like you need some better debugging to figure out what is happening, such as logging the ID of messages that are received, processed and deleted. It should also log when the subprocess _starts_ processing a message and _finishes_ processing it, to see whether something failed in the subprocess.

Comment: I tried logging stuff, the subprocess starts the script and length of 'm' is zero, the process exits. But then I go check SQS which shows the messages were consumed.

Comment: If `queue.receive_messages()` returns something, then it will extract one message from the list of messages and then call `process_message()` (which you have not shown us). What do you mean by "length of 'm' is zero" -- the only place you have shown us the `m` variable is just before calling `process_message()`. Perhaps you need to show us additional code and the results of your debugging?

Comment: queue.receive_messages() returns list of messages, either many if specified or just one. It returns empty list for me even when there are messages in queue. But thanks to you, I figured the issue.

Comment: If your solution will be useful to other people, feel free to add it as an Answer to your own question. Or, if you think it won't help people (due to it being caused by a mistake somewhere else), feel free to Delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

`m = queue.receive_messages(WaitTimeSeconds=5)`

This will resolve the issue because in cases where there are very less amount of messages in SQS, polling for messages will be very likely to fail.

You can read about short-polling on boto3 docs here.
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Queue.receive_messages

Comment: The parameter controls how long the request should wait before returning an empty result (maximum value of 20 seconds). This should not have caused an issue with your application, since it would frequently receive zero messages anyway. So, I'm glad you managed to fix it, but I can't see how this was the cause of the problem.